# What does this jQuery code mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain the meaning of this code?

```
if (data.result) {
    $('ul#intlist').append(data.content);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is basically checking whether some data exists `if(data.result)` and then appends the content of the data to the end of an `ul` with an ID of `intlist`

So if you had an UL as follows:

```
<ul id="intlist">
   ...
</ul>
```

Then the jQuery code would be inserting the result of `data.content` to this list.

In jQuery you can use CSS selectors to gain access to the elements you want. If you were to do `$('ul')` this would give you access to all ul's on the page. If you were to do `$('#intlist')` this would give you access to an element with an id of "intlist". You can combine these selectors as in your code above so that `$('ul#intlist')` is getting an ul with the id of "intlist". The hash `#` symbol is used to obtain items by Id.

You can read more about jQuerys `append()` method here: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

if the returning `data` from what I'm guessing is an AJAX-call has a property `result` which is not set to `false` or `0`, then get the unordered list with an id `intlist` and append whatever is in the `content` property of the returning data.